# C# MVC Class Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help me get around my problem with my class please?

I have an Address class:

```
public class Address
{
    public string addressDescription { get; set; }
    public string addressNumber { get; set; }
    public string adddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string adddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string adddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string addressPostCode { get; set; }
    public double addressLatitude { get; set; }
    public double addressLongitude { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a Route Class:

```
public class Route
{
    public Address from { get; set; }
    public Address to { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller i have setup some dummy information like this:

```
public ActionResult FareCalculator(string from , string to)
    {

        var myroute = new Route();

        myroute.from.addressDescription = from;
        myroute.from.addressLatitude = 51.481581;
        myroute.from.addressLongitude = -3.179090;
        myroute.to.addressDescription = to;
        myroute.to.addressLatitude = 51.507335;
        myroute.to.addressLongitude = -0.127683;

        return View(myroute);
    }
```

but when i run the project it falls over on the myroute.from.addressDescription = from; line saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Trev

Comment: The correct answers are below, but you should consider renaming route to something else.  Route means something in MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Address` and assign it to `from` and `to`:

```
public ActionResult FareCalculator(string from , string to)
{

    var myroute = new Route();
    myroute.from = new Address(); // new instance
    myroute.from.addressDescription = from;
    myroute.from.addressLatitude = 51.481581;
    myroute.from.addressLongitude = -3.179090;

    myroute.to = new Address(); // new instance
    myroute.to.addressDescription = to;
    myroute.to.addressLatitude = 51.507335;
    myroute.to.addressLongitude = -0.127683;

    return View(myroute);
}
```

Comment: @TrevorDaniel do you know that you can accept answers? There is a checkmark thingy next below the vote buttons. That way you can mark the question as answered. I noted that you did not accept any questions yet. Helps others from not having to read the Q&A for "solved questions". PS +1 for Darren for keeping me awake.:)

Comment: @DarrenDavies back on the stack ;)

Comment: @mattytommo I'm an addict ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies +1 to you, you'll be 10k in no time ;)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest to use the constructor to initialize the from and to fields? Otherwise you will have to new the objects every time you use the Route class.

```
public class Route
{
    public Address from { get; set; }
    public Address to { get; set; }

    public Route()
    {
        from = new Address();
        to = new Address();
    }
}
```

That way you can use your code as you provided:

```
    var myroute = new Route();

    myroute.from.addressDescription = from;
    myroute.from.addressLatitude = 51.481581;
    myroute.from.addressLongitude = -3.179090;
    myroute.to.addressDescription = to;
    myroute.to.addressLatitude = 51.507335;
    myroute.to.addressLongitude = -0.127683;

    return View(myroute);
```

Comment: no it shouldn't contain quotes as from is a string.  He is simply assigning addressDescription to this variable.  The problem lies with that from and to had no instance of Address.

Comment: yeah I realise that but assigning addressDescription to "from" would not give the OP the correct output.

Comment: I think that's exactly what he's trying to do, but lets not try to think for him. I'll remove the addition then.

Comment: why would he pass in a string called from containing the data if he wanted to assign it to the string literal "from"?

Comment: I didn't say it was meaningful, but that's what the code example looks like.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, oh dear god, nevermind me. Apparently I am going blind... didn't see the parameters from and to.... oops!

Answer (score 1):

You have created `Route` instance, but you have forgotten to create new instances of `Address` (for `from` and `to`):

```
var myroute = new Route
{
    from = new Address(),
    to = new Address()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`myroute.from` and `myroute.to` shoud be an instance of `Address` class.

```
 public ActionResult FareCalculator(string from , string to)
 {
        var myroute = new Route();

        myroute.from = new Address();
        myroute.from.addressDescription = from;
        myroute.from.addressLatitude = 51.481581;
        myroute.from.addressLongitude = -3.179090;

        myroute.to = new Address();
        myroute.to.addressDescription = to;
        myroute.to.addressLatitude = 51.507335;
        myroute.to.addressLongitude = -0.127683;

        return View(myroute);
    }
```